# Grails cascade delete

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

In my Grails domain I have a 1:1 relationship between `Artist` and `MusicianDetails`

```
class Artist {

    static hasOne = [musicianDetails: MusicianDetails]

    static constraints = {
        musicianDetails(nullable: true, unique: true)
    }           
}

class MusicianDetails {
    static belongsTo = [artist: Artist]
}
```

I want deletes of `Artist` to cascade to the associated `MusicianDetails`. However, I get a foreign key contraint violation when I delete an `Artist` with:

```
Artist.executeUpdate("delete Artist a where a.id = ?", [artistId])
```

The error message is:

```
Class
    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException
Message
    Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails 
    (`festival2`.`musician_details`, CONSTRAINT `FKA0E6B2145ACE528E` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`artist_id`) REFERENCES `artist` (`id`))
```

What is the correct way to defined a 1:1 relationship between `Artist` and `MusicianDetails` such that deletes of the former cascade to the latter?

Answer (score 1):

The cascading works if I delete the artist using

```
artist.get(artistId)?.delete()
```

instead of

```
Artist.executeUpdate("delete Artist a where a.id = ?", [artistId])
```

Comment: That's because HQL updates/deletes go directly to the database (translated), and do not execute Hibernate events, which are responsible for deleting the orphans (it's not a trigger in the DB )

Answer (score 0):

You need a belongsTo in MusicianDetails. Not sure but you might also need to cascade all-delete-orphan.

Anyways it seems as if Musician Details can be an embedded class of Artist, so that it is mapped to one database table.

http://bartling.blogspot.com/2009/04/embedded-domain-components-in-grails.html?m=1

Another thing is, that it is better to do Artist.get(artistId).delete() instead of executing a HQL query. This makes code less prone to errors, more understandable and you can always change GORM to another implementation if you want to get rid of Hibernate for any reason.